# Why is my custom route not working?

Tags: routes, 9

I'm writing a module that integrates the Zoom API and subscribes to calls, but I'm stuck on just testing my controller code, as Drupal doesn't recognize the route used by the module.

#### zoom_call_module.routing.yml

```yaml
zoom_call_module.content:
  path: '/zoom_call_module'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\zoom_call_module\Controller\ZoomCallModuleController::content'
    _title: 'Zoom Call Module'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

#### ZoomCallModuleController.php

```php
namespace Drupal\zoom_call_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

/**
 * Defines ZoomCallModuleController class.
 */
class ZoomCallModuleController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Display the markup.
   *
   * @return array
   *   Return markup array.
   */
  public function content() {
    $build = [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Test Succeeded!'),
    ];
    
    return $build;
  }

}
```

Accessing /zoom_call_module, I get a page with the following message.

> The requested page could not be found.

> [image: Result]

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Is the module installed? Did you rebuild the cache?

Comment: Yes and yes. Uninstalling, clearing cache and reinstalling hasn't helped either.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the controller inside the correct folder structure. It needs to be in `zoom_call_module/src/Controller/ZoomCallModuleController.php`